# How do I get the default value of a column in DB2 DBMS using MyBatis?

Tags: db2

A table and column were created using the syntax below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "TABLE2" (
    "COL"  VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT 11111,
    "COL2" VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT 22222, 
    "COL3" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT 33333 
);

COMMENT ON COLUMN "TABLE2"."COL" IS '새 컬럼 주석';

COMMENT ON COLUMN "TABLE2"."COL2" IS '새 컬럼2 주석';

COMMENT ON COLUMN "TABLE2"."COL3" IS '새 컬럼3 주석';
```

And I wrote the following logic to get the default value of the column with MyBatis.

```java
// ...
SqlSession sqlSession = reverseInfo.getSqlSession();
List<E> result = sqlSession.selectList(statement, parameter);
```

The associated mapper class is:

```java
@Mapper
public Map<String, Object> selectColumn(Map<String, Object> map);
```

The linked xml is:

```sql
SELECT
 -- ...
    syscat.columns.default AS DEFAULT_VALUE
    syscat.columns.nulls AS NULLABLE
    syscat.columns.remarks AS COMMENT
FROM    syscat.columns
INNER JOIN syscat.datatypes
ON syscat.columns.typename = syscat.datatypes.typename
```

And when you get it

Other columns are called classes such as String, Integer, etc.
DEFAULT VALUE is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.he@11799617

The value cannot be checked because it appears as a type such as:

How can I find out?

Comment: SYSCAT.COLUMNS.DEFAULT is a CLOB. I read CLOBs all day as strings.